# clean way of concatenating strings and variables?

Tags: bash

This looks dirty:

```
echo "GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/""$1"" git checkout -f" >> hooks/post-receive
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this concatenation? Where `$1` is a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you want to accomplish, but this might work for you:

```
echo "GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/${1} git checkout -f" >> hooks/post-receive
```

Comment: Agh, that looks cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: Will that not break if I have spaces in `$1`

Comment: @Severus, yes, but so will your original one. Try using `"GIT_...='/var/www/${1}' git ..."` with single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/$1 git checkout -f" >> hooks/post-receive
```

will also work.
also you can separate the variable from other text with curly braces like this:

```
echo "tetxtetxetext${VAR}textetxtetext"
```